# Create Folder of Files on S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

Currently, my S3 bucket contains files. I want to create a folder for each file on S3.

Current -> `s3://<bucket>/test.txt`

Expectation -> `s3://<bucket>/test/test.txt`

How can I achieve this using the EC2 instance?

Comment: Could you please clarify your requirements? Are you wanting to put the objects into folders **when they are uploaded**, or are you wanting to move existing objects into folders? Also, please let us know how you are uploading the files to S3, because you can put them in such folders immediately if desired. Oh, and what have you tried so far? (Please edit your question to clarify these details rather than answering in a comment.)

Answer (score 0):

S3 doesn't have "folders" really, object names may contain `/` characters in them and that in a way emulates folders. Simply name your objects `test/<filename>` to achieve that. See the [S3 docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/using-folders.html) for more.

As for doing it from EC2, it is no different from doing it from anywhere else (except, maybe, in EC2 you may be able to rely on an IAM profile instead of using ad-hoc credentials). If you've tried it and failed, maybe post a new question with more details.

Comment: Currently i have file in form  -> s3://<bucket>/test.txt and i wanto convert that in s3://<bucket>/test/test.txt

Comment: @MihirGarg look up the documentation on how to rename an object in S3, using the S3 API or any tool available to you.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Linux you can try something like:

```
aws s3 ls s3://bucket/ | while read date time size name; do aws s3 mv s3://bucket/${name} s3://bucket/`echo ${name%.*}`/${name}; done
```

Answer (score 0):

it does not depend upon EC2 instance. You can use aws cli from EC2 instance or some other source with putting desired path, for your case s3:///test/test.txt. you can even change the name of the file you are copying into s3 bucket even its extension if you want.